# Unable to use Rcpp after conda install

Tags: r, rcpp, conda

I installed R with conda

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

Now I cannot use the `Rcpp` library, even so it is installed with `r-essentials`. I get the following error:

```
# using library inline to compile a C++ code on the fly
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
src <- '
   std::vector<std::string> s;
   s.push_back("hello");
   s.push_back("world");
   return Rcpp::wrap(s);
'
hellofun <- cxxfunction(body = src, includes = '', plugin = 'Rcpp', verbose = FALSE)
cat(hellofun(), '\n')


Error in dyn.load(libLFile): unable to load shared object '/tmp/Rtmp5N7UzX/file3a485578682c.so':
  /tmp/Rtmp5N7UzX/file3a485578682c.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_
Traceback:

1. cxxfunction(body = src, includes = "", plugin = "Rcpp", verbose = FALSE)
2. dyn.load(libLFile)
```

I believe that this also affects compilation of modules not included in conda like `rstan`, which installation failed with a similar error.

Comment: Could you try just: `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")`?

Comment: This gives the same error.

Comment: Please complain loudly and clearly to Continuum for breaking what are reliable and working R setups.  But for what it is worth: we (as in the R community, and Team Rcpp in particular) support the CRAN installations.  For the rest, you are on your own, maybe with help from Continuum.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, however updating a response I received on Github.

I faced the same error with different package installation (in my case it was BCP). Based on the solution/work around provided [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3885), the error in `dyn.load()` is no longer appearing. So it may be worth a try to update the R version using `conda update  r-essentials`.

Comment: I had an issue while installing phangorn package, which dependes on Rcpp. After reading the thread you linked I did just `conda install gcc` and then it compiled successfully, so - thanks a ton! :)