# Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

Tags: r

I am trying to install Deseq2, however I get this error. The same appears for all other packages I try to install with BiocLite...I wonder what is the problem? I installed R and rstudio with anaconda on my ubuntu 16.04. R version 3.3.2. Any help is much appreciated.

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/dani/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tidyr/libs/tidyr.so':
  /home/dani/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tidyr/libs/tidyr.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/dani/anaconda2/lib/R/library/tidyr’
* restoring previous ‘/home/danianaconda2/lib/R/library/tidyr’
```

does it has something to do with this error at the beginning?

```
Makevars:21: Makevars.local: No such file or directory
touch: "Makevars.local"
```

Comment: You may need to contact package developers. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333691/unable-to-use-rcpp-after-conda-install#comment67922991_40333691) may give some clue as to why.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best solution: I was using anaconda version 4.3.1 and I changed it to 4.1.1 and reinstalled all using this version, R remained always v 3.3.2. So I don't know if there is a bug or some incompatibility problem with Rcpp package or else in the last version of conda.